Can you compute the common connection?
Each group in this connect-wall shares a number having those properties.











Aliquot sum is a prime
Catalan
Digit sum is a cube
Exponent of isolated Mersenne prime


Fibonacci
Friendly
Hexagonal
Lucas


Multidigit nonary xenodrome
Octagonal
Octahedral
Perfect


Semiprime + 1
Square
Square + 1
Triangular




Partition the properties into 4 groups of 4 to get 4 numbers.
Bonus challenge: Can you prove that there's only one way to do this?
Find another property such that these 4 numbers are the smallest that have it.
Question: What's the next smallest?


The numbers corresponding to the groups are

 1 is a square, square + 1, Lucas, and Catalan number


 6 is a perfect, friendly, octahedral, and hexagonal number


 21 is a triangular, octagonal, Fibonacci number, and its aliquot sum is a prime


 107 is a semiprime + 1, multidigit nonary xenodrome, exponent of an isolated Mersenne prime, and its digit sum is a cube

My reasoning

 Looking at Mersenne exponents, 7 does not have enough candidates to be a group, so 17 and 107 are suitable to start checking instead. Trying out 107 as a group, this forced the digit sum (8 is a cube), Semiprime+1, and the multidigit nonary xenodrome, as they are the only sequences with the number 107.


 Next the perfect numbers seemed to constrain another group to either 6 or 28, with 6 working better. The aliquot sum sequence had 21, 55, and 65 potentially, with 21 being the most accessible. Keeping this in mind, there are 5 sequences with the number 6 in it, and if the triangular number sequence was excluded that would leave it available for the 21's.


 The perfect and friendly sequences paired together nicely for 6, and octahedral and hexagonal completed that group. Leaving the triangular number out of the 6 grouping allowed the 21 group, along with octagonal, Fibonacci and the aliquot sum.


 The only number left that still had enough candidates for a group is 1, which comprised of Square, Square+1, Lucas, and Catalan.

To summarise my solve process:

 for each integer, count the number of sequences that it is in, and if there are 4 or more, check that the different combinations of groupings don't lead to a contradiction. Sequences with sparse members are forced to be in different groups, such as Mersenne exponents, Perfect numbers, and prime aliquot sums.

For the second part of the question,

 the Busy Beaver sequence starts with these four numbers (1, 6, 21, 107). The next term in the sequence is 47176870.


Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Like you suggested, zero and one seem a bit "trivial" to be solutions. Maybe there are other solutions?

@noedne I think I misinterpreted that to mean s(n)=7 itself is an aliquot sum (namely of n=8) and being prime.

It would be nice to link each OEIS entry in your solution :)

Nice work! The final answer is the largest number known in the sequence, and was finally proven correct earlier this year after 35 years. Here's a good article about its journey.

@BenjaminWang added, thanks for the format cleanup as well!
